# Reading public Key from an X509 structure in Javascript

Tags: javascript, public-key, x509certificate2

Hello I have an encoded public key with a X509 structure and I want to extract modulus and the public exponent from it I'm using the following ASN.1 Decoder http://lapo.it/asn1js/to read the key but I can't see the modulus or the public exponent in the result I get.

This is the key I want to read.

```
30819e300d06092a864886f70d010101050003818c00308188028180599a96c54ef07f5288a061a56386376fd9e2e0a253cb035f2b0c65c85c99153a848a8247d9e28d8be1dbad5e754e8393e591cc53e5abec2f0a44b4844646cc283123fdd799c50dd5acd1277fd9afeb9c5a12a53b9edfff0ac53d6e94e5f1678c3bd0ccd8d08b18d4a42f845b79b8b19203e24e189801ca396f5732bfe628edeb0203010001
```

This is the result I get from the decoder.

```
SEQUENCE(2 elem)
SEQUENCE(2 elem)
OBJECT IDENTIFIER1.2.840.113549.1.1.1
NULL
BIT STRING(1 elem)
SEQUENCE(2 elem)
INTEGER(1023 bit)
INTEGER65537
```

Thanks in advance.

```
//Example of what I am expecting to find.
    30 819f // SEQUENCE
      30 0d // SEQUENCE
        06 09 2a864886f70d010101 // OBJECT IDENTIFIER of RSA
        05 00 // NULL (parameter)
      03 818d // BIT STRING
        00 // using all following bits
        30 8189 // SEQUENCE
          02 8181 // (signed) INTEGER
            00 // padding (signed INTEGER) followed by the modulus
            95e15f182ec7b6e84786c0ee54e3bb72af0461e6fd859a3625f38dcd3fdec80d
            fcc51a44756ec7cd6c14b430d55670460c5143efadd1ade7380e890e9957d6e6
            b38f35412862cc955e04d1928f21c0d2f7bc48c3855276f0e7c1b45a558e3a01
            3b969cbfaebca42b748e64bff787f86ec5f0adcd94428c4ab8ca6d2b710d785b
          02 03 // (signed) INTEGER
            010001 // public exponent (4th number of Fermat)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using asn1js like this,

```
var hex = Hex.decode("30819e300d06..."); // key truncated for this example

// decode key
var mykey = ASN1.decode(hex);
```

You first need to find where the modulus bytes start as well as modulus length

```
var modStart = mykey.sub[1].sub[0].sub[0].posContent();
var modLen = mykey.sub[1].sub[0].sub[0].length;
```

Now loop over the stream and populate a `modbytes` array

```
// read modulus bytes
var modbytes = [];

for(var x = 0; x < modLen; x++) {
    modbytes.push(mykey.stream.enc[x+modStart]);
}

// modbytes now contains array like [89, 154, 150, 197, 78...]
```

Since the exponent is an integer, it can be easily read like this

```
var exponent = mykey.sub[1].sub[0].sub[1].content();
// returns 65537
```

You can convert the values to a hex like so,

```
// in the case of the exponent its simple
exponent.toString(16); // returns "10001"
```

As for the modulus you need to iterate over the modulus bytes and concatenate their hex values

```
var modulusHex = "";
for(var x = 0; x < modbytes.length; x++) {
    var hexByte = modbytes[x].toString(16);

    // might need padding before appending
    modulusHex += (hexByte.length == 1) ? "0"+hexByte : hexByte;
}

// modulusHex now contains something like
// 599a96c54ef07f5288a061a5...
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer I implemented your  solution and I get the exponent 66537 and for the modulus bytes I get :                   89,154,150,197,78,240,127,82,136,160,97,165,99,134,55,111,217,226,224,162,83,203,3,95,43,12,101,200,92,153,21,58,132,138,130,71,217,226,141,139,225,219,173,94,117,78,131,147,229,145,204,83,229,171,236,47,10,68,180,132,70,70,204,40,49,35,253,215,153,197,13,213,172,209,39,1......//Truncated           So this is only the modulus bytes not the modulus itself right? How can I get it? The purpose is to recreate the public key. Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by 'the modulus itself' ? do you have an example of the type of output you have in mind?

Comment: Take a look at your last answer please I put the type of output I'm expecting to find. Thanks

Comment: your edit somehow got lost but I think you wanted a hex representation, please check updated answer

Comment: @oussamakamal please accept the answer so that other users know that this answer solved your problem